# bootstrap 3: why do my <div>s stack from 992 px width onwards when using "col-sm-6"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap 3. I'm having issues with the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid .
Everything works well below 992px. In other words, <728 px my two divs stack, >728 px they are horizontal. However, above 992px they stack AGAIN. My aim is that my two divs only stack for "Extra small devices Phones (<768px)". Not for bigger screens.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="container">
        <div class ="row">
            <div class ="col-sm-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class ="col-sm-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <!-- JavaScript plugins (requires jQuery) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Enable responsive features in IE8 with Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -->
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Have a look at the images, please. It's not working for me (neither in FF nor in Chrome).
[image: Here it works] Picture one works.

Making the screen wider, it starts stacking:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctXzj)

Comment: What buid of 3 are you using? It seems to work as expected with the latest (RC1) - http://bootply.com/73934

Comment: Thx for the demos, guys. This is really odd. 
@Skelly: Using RC1. Tested in two browsers. Thx for your help, anyway. At least I have a clue now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the grid classes ( col-sm-# and col-lg-# ) in Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146775/understanding-the-grid-classes-col-sm-and-col-lg-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2):

Add classes below to each of your blocks, that have to be stacked one under another in small version.

col-lg-6 col-sm-12

col-lg-6 says: 
Make block 50% width in LG and smaller dimensions

col-sm-12 says: 
Make block 100% width in SM and smaller dimensions

Zoom. It's expected behavior. Zoom would change your page_width/element_width ratio. 
So you will get other breakpoint usually after zooming.