# Bootstrap 3: is col-xs-12 optional?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

We have

```
<div class="col-md-6">left</div>
<div class="col-md-6">right</div>
```

For smaller screens than `md`, we'd like to have it in two lines. Looks like it is displayed as expected. Perfect.

The same result is when we add `col-xs-12` so it is

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">left</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">right</div>
```

That's  one line for large screens and two lines for small screens.

**The question is:**

As result, is `col-xs-12` class optional in this case or it is recommended?

Comment: You can have a look at this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146775/understanding-the-grid-classes-col-sm-and-col-lg-in-bootstrap-3). Explains how the grid works.

Comment: @iamemmanouil Thank you. I understand I shouldn't type col-lg-6 and col-sm-12. That's clear. The question was about col-xs-12 only in the case above. Should it be voided or it is recommended? Looks like the result is the same in both cases.

Comment: Technically you don't need it & I don't use any responsive framework's small classes unless they are needed. It's extra typing & classes that aren't needed to accomplish the same thing. I would only add the col-xs- in this case if it's anything other than 12 (full-width). To go further, it works small to large. So if you need large & small to be 6 columns each, you can just do one class of col-xs-6 and that transfers up to everything above it unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I previously thought that it may be a good idea to add `col-xs-12` so default padding would be applied to element. But if you take a closer look at bootstrap's css, you would notice padding is defined somewhere else

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

So padding is automatically applied to all elements that have at least one `col-*-*` class no matter of current `@media` screen size applied.

To answer your question: **Yes, col-xs-12** (and other `col-*-12` as well) **is optional** and you don't have to use it **as long as you have at least one `col-*-*` class** applied to element.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but today I came the sad realization that `col-xs-12` (and probably other `col-*-12` as well.) aren't really optional as I also thought. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602234/88709). Now back to adding missing col-xs-12's…

Comment: indeed padding is fine as long as you have at least one other `col-*-*` rule in place. Keep in mind that in case you would like to have a row breaking behaviour on certain devices ((e.g. `col-xs-6`, `col-xs-6`, `col-xs-12`; so that the last element breaks to the next row) this won't work because of the missing `width:100%`. With a custom rule applied to the desired element you could easily fix that. The question is now if that is better that having an explicit `col-xs-12` on the element. Probably I prefer to keep it in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: although optional, you might need `col-xs-12` anyway**

[image]

At least in Bootstrap 3.4.1, omitting it will cause issues in smaller screen sizes. Elements that don't have `col-xs-12` won't have its corresponding `float: left; width: 100%;` styles either. This will cause them to grow taller, obscuring elements above, and preventing them to gain focus.

I put together [this pen](https://codepen.io/daniel-liuzzi/pen/bGErqyp) to show the problem in action.

**Related**

- [Bootstrap Large column overlay medium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42990539/88709)
- [Column with different breakpoint obscures preceding column](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17998)