# What is the difference between various types of col types in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to bootstrap on ASP.NET MVC. I would like to know what is the difference between the following col types?

```
col-lg-##  
col-md-##
col-sm-##
col-xs-##
```

When is the ideal type to be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the grid classes ( col-sm-# and col-lg-# ) in Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146775/understanding-the-grid-classes-col-sm-and-col-lg-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Take a look at the bootstrap docs; it is very well documented. What you are looking for is the "Grid System" section of the CSS documentation. http://getbootstrap.com/css

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend spending some time with the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid 
Generally, the size indications correspond to the screen size in which you are creating the layout....
xs - Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
sm - Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
md - Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
lg - Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)