# How make a responsive carousel of 3 cards using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Here is the Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp23v.png)

On the image as shown how to create such cards with carousel in each page it will appear as 3 and in mobile mode it will shown as one card How to do it using Bootstrap or without bootstrap any suggestion?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the grid classes ( col-sm-# and col-lg-# ) in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146775/understanding-the-grid-classes-col-sm-and-col-lg-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1):

try using grids in boostrap and divide the cards by column. for example if you have 12 grids, you'll use `col-lg-4` for big desktops and then `col-xs-12` for small devices.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/nattygurl/52zbb0gj/)

try minimizing the screen and see the responsiveness